# use trex test vpp performance, memif can't connnect

Tags: cisco, dpdk

The goal is to connect TREX packet generator with VPP memif interface on the same Host. The memif Interface fails to get connected with the following logs

**Failed with info:**

```
Apr 28 15:12:24 xx[370159]: memif_connect_client(): Failed to connect socket: /run/vpp/memif.sock.
Apr 28 15:12:25 xx[370159]: EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1#012  Cause:
Apr 28 15:12:25 xx[370159]: rte_eth_dev_start: err=-1, port=0
```

vpp version: 19.08.3
trex version: v2.89

```
vpp# show memif

sockets
  id  listener    filename
  0   yes (2)     /run/vpp/memif.sock

interface memif0/0
  socket-id 0 id 0 mode ethernet
  flags admin-up
  listener-fd 49 conn-fd 0
  num-s2m-rings 0 num-m2s-rings 0 buffer-size 0 num-regions 0
interface memif0/1
  socket-id 0 id 1 mode ethernet
  flags admin-up
  listener-fd 49 conn-fd 0
  num-s2m-rings 0 num-m2s-rings 0 buffer-size 0 num-regions 0
```

```
# cat /etc/trex_cfg.yaml**
- version: 2
  interfaces: ["--vdev=net_memif0,role=slave,id=0,socket=/run/vpp/memif.sock",
                 "--vdev=net_memif1,role=slave,id=1,socket=/run/vpp/memif.sock"]
  port_info:
      - ip: 172.21.0.253
        default_gw: 172.21.0.254
      - ip: 192.168.1.254
        default_gw: 192.168.1.253

  platform:
      master_thread_id: 16
      latency_thread_id: 17
      dual_if:
        - socket: 0
          threads: [18,19]
```

Comment: can you please cross check if it is typo in specifying the same file for 2 ports `socket=/run/vpp/memif.sock`  in trex_cfg.yaml?

Comment: is there any updates at your end @IdeaWi ?

Answer (score 0):

DPDK memif PMD has two modes of operation

1. Client mode
2. Server mode

The sequence of start also affects how memif communicate and connects to listener (server).

So if we need to make VPP as server and TREX as client use (always start VPP first and create memif interface)

```
create interface memif id 0 master
set interface state memif0/0 up
set interface ip address memif0/0 12.12.5.1/24

and

--vdev=net_memif0,role=client,id=0,socket=/run/vpp/memif.sock
```

if we need to make TREX server and VPP client use (always start TREX first)

```
--vdev=net_memif0,role=server,id=0,socket=/run/vpp/memif.sock

and

create interface memif id 0 slave
set interface state memif0/0 up
set interface ip address memif0/0 12.12.5.2/24
```

note:

- if more than 1 interface is required, ensure VPP creates memif interface 0 and 1 on separate sockets.
- tested the same with dpdk-pktgen and vpp.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Trex 2.92 has been upgraded to use DPDK version 21.02

In interface in `/etc/trex_cfg.yaml`, instead of:

```
interfaces: ["--vdev=net_memif0,role=slave,id=0,socket=/run/vpp/memif.sock",
```

it should be

```
interfaces: ["--vdev=net_memif0,role=slave,id=0,socket-abstract=no,socket=/run/vpp/memif.sock",
```

as by default it assumes the socket path as raw socket path.

Comment: @PragyaNanBhagat as per DPDK PMD documentation https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/memif.html, the default value is `no` for `socket-abstract`. So the real question is have you encountered any issue within TREX 2.92 by not passing the argument and letting the driver (memif PMD) pick up default value? If yes, I highly support to open a new ticket and answering the same with error logs. It will be helpful for others

Comment: @VipinVarghese looks like default value is yes, in the link provided by you in Table 34.1 Memif configuration options, there is a column "Default" where default value for "socket-abstract" is given as "yes". Please verify.

Comment: @PragyaNanBhagat I did not follow you, as per the documentation shared `socket-abstract=no Set usage of abstract socket address`. Default value is `no`. You are suggesting to passing as `no`. Also checking the driver code https://git.dpdk.org/dpdk/tree/drivers/net/memif/rte_eth_memif.c, the flag `ETH_MEMIF_FLAG_SOCKET_ABSTRACT` is only set if it is `yes` else default falg is `0`. Can you please explain what is your claim, have really encountered error in TREX? If yes, I request you to open a new ticket and answer the same as it will help others.

Comment: @VipinVarghese if you scroll to right in the same table it gives a column for default values which says default value is yes. Please verify.

Comment: thanks for sharing your answer, but as shared with respect to DPDK documentation default value for `socket-abstract=yes` and pmd code sets the default as `flags |= ETH_MEMIF_FLAG_SOCKET_ABSTRACT;`. Question I have been asking is abstract socket works on linux, the question is asked for VPP running on linux. Can you please elaborate why you need to switch of abstract socket?

Comment: we need to switch off the abstract socket as it will prepend "@" in the beginning of the socket parameter passed in the trex_cfg file, so in this question if the user passes "/run/vpp/memif.sock" as socket file it becomes "@/run/vpp/memif.sock" and since it is a different address(of socket file), trex wont be able to connect to vpp memif as for vpp memif the socket is "/run/vpp/memif.sock". This I have tested with vpp and trex.

Comment: @PragayaNanBhat original question posted by Wei (based on the dpdk and trex) version had issue with the path which is later clarified via Intel email. With respect current conversation TREX uses DPDK memif PMD and VPP has the memif inbuilt to it. SO if DPDK application and TREX uses same version of DPDK, why do you think `@` (siocket abstraction) is causing failure in lInux? My hints in comments so far has been to help you call out the reasoning that is `VPP version in use does not use socket abstraction`. But so far I did not clear reasoning in the answer.